# null pointer exception on AsynchCallback

Tags: java, gwt, google-maps-api-3, nullpointerexception

This is my method.

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(PlotSetOutput result) {
            String test = result.toString(); // this works
        controller.getScolopaxGUI().getResultsPanel().setPlots(result);
        controller.getScolopaxGUI().displayTab(1);
    }
```

In my setPlots method I am trying to display the results on GoogleMaps. I set a breakpoint
inside the setPlots and it seems the code fails before that.
I am successfully able to get the ResultPanel object too. Hence I am confused as to what is causing this NullPointerException.

```
06:47:38.791 [ERROR] [scolopax] Uncaught exception escaped
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at edu.neu.scolopax.web.client.RetrieveSummariesAsynchCallback.onSuccess(RetrieveSummariesAsynchCallback.java:32)
    at edu.neu.scolopax.web.client.RetrieveSummariesAsynchCallback.onSuccess(RetrieveSummariesAsynchCallback.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:258)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: what is the 32nd line here

Comment: The line where I invoke the set plots method. controller.getScolopaxGUI().getResultsPanel().setPlots(result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

one of the following is null

```
controller

controller.getScolopaxGUI()    

controller.getScolopaxGUI().getResultsPanel()
```

try this

```
    if(controller != null &&  controller.getScolopaxGUI() != null && 
 controller.getScolopaxGUI().getResultsPanel() != null)
     controller.getScolopaxGUI().getResultsPanel().setPlots(result);
```

Comment: @Yeshwanth Venkatesh you are wel come